# JavaFX updating Canvas from another Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, canvas, javafx

I am trying to visualize a BubbleSort within a Canvas.
To slow the drawing in the Canvas down, I'm using Thread.sleep().
Therefore I need another Thread, so my GUI won't freeze.

After every iteration, I want to update my Canvas.

I've been able to come up with a semi-working solution as follows:

```
public void bubbleSort(){
    Task task = new Task() {
        @Override
        protected Object call() throws Exception {
            int n = array.length - 1;
            int temp;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = n; j > i; j--)
                {
                    if (Integer.compare(array[j -1],array[j]) > 0)
                    {
                        temp = array[j - 1];
                        array[j - 1] = array[j];
                        array[j] = temp;

                    }
                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                         @Override public void run() {
                             drawChart();
                         }
                     });
                    Thread.sleep(sleep);    
                } 
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
    Thread t = new Thread(task);
    t.setName("sortingthread");
    t.setDaemon(true);
    t.start();
}
```

However, this will spam the event Queue with alot of Runnables and I don't think this is a good solution.
It's also kind of not what I want exactly because the loop will iterate a couple of times, and then the drawchart() method is called a couple of times within runnables.

Hope anyone could help me with this.

Comment: Unless sleep is not smaller than 1/60 s there is nothing wrong with this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer why exactly 1/60s?

Comment: The rendering of the UI is driven by pulses and on the UI thread there are at max 60 pulses per second, which results in 60 fps max. See https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/architecture/jfxpub-architecture.htm

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look at it!